# Hiding table rows if any of the two columns is empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Have a 2 columned table, where each column consists of another table with some data, what I am trying to do is to hide the entire row if both of the columns are empty.. can anybody share some inputs on it..

http://jsfiddle.net/m38uL/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you had already was close to working, but you had an error in your `if` statement:

```
if ($(this).find('.firstTab').text() == '' && (this).find('.secondTab').text() == '')
```

Notice the missing `$` in the second condition. It also would fail if there was white space in the `.firstTab` and `.secondTab` elements. Personally, I would write the code slightly differently, using the `filter` method, and `.trim` to remove any white space at the start or end of the content:

```
$(".parentRow > td").filter(function() {
       return $.trim($(this).find(".firstTab").text) == "" && $.trim($(this).find(".secondTab").text()) == "";
}).remove();
```

Here's a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/m38uL/3/) of the above code.

Comment: have a small problem with that code, the column is removed if its empty, that should happen only if both table is empty in that row.. can u suggest how to change it

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
// loop through each row...
$('.parentRow').each(function() {      
  var rowEmpty = true;

   // check each cell in the row to see if it's got anything in it
   $($this).find('td').each(function(){
       if($(this).html() != "")
       {
           rowEmpty = false;
       }
   });

   // if the row was empty, hide it
   if(rowEmpty)
   {
    $(this).hide();   
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('.parentRow').each(function() {
    if ($(".firstTab", this).text() === '' && $('.secondTab', this).text() === '')
    {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```